# Regular expression to replace shortest match

Tags: regex, regular-language

my string is like this
sfdfdsfdsf**start112matlab2336end**gfdgdfgkknfkg**start558899end**dfdsfd

how can we replace part of a string such a way that the result will be

sfdfdsfdsfgfdgdfgkknfkgdfdsfd

i.e bolded content need to be removed.

Comment: ya i tried "start.*end" but it is matching the first start and last end

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) matching:

```
start.*?end
```

Answer (score 5):

Use replacement function with this regex `/start.+?end/g` which will match the bold parts of your string. The `g` part of the regex means globally, and might need to be implemented differently depending on the language you use.

The key here is to use `?` which turns on un-greedy matching. That means the match consumes the minimum amount of characters rather than the maximum, so will match from the `start` to the next rather than the last `end`

Answer (score 0):

```
start[1-9]+end
```

if you need to have numbers between words

Comment: It does not seem to be the case.